# Matrix reflection

Tags: matrices

I've been given the matrix for reflecting a plane P, which is
$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{11}{15} & \frac{2}{15} & \frac{2}{3} \\ \frac{2}{15} & \frac{14}{15} & -\frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \end{pmatrix}$$
I know that I should apply the 3x3 identity matrix here, which gives me
$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{11}{15} & \frac{2}{15} & \frac{2}{3} \\ \frac{2}{15} & \frac{14}{15} & -\frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} - 2  \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}^T$$ by the Wikipedia definition. However, I'm not quite clear as to what T should be and how I should move forwards with this problem.

Comment: Do you mean $T$ to be the linear transformation? And what's the problem you're trying to solve? Thx

Comment: I'm trying to find a, b, and c. Also, T is the linear transformation.

Comment: I've edited the equation to make it appear in one line. But thank you also for teaching me that `\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}` works without `$...$` :)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if your matrix is denoted by $A$ then we have $A^T A=I$. Your matrix is an orthogonal matrix. Thus an important observation is that this matrix will send a normal vector $\vec{n}=(a,b,c)$ of the plane being reflected to $(-a,-b,-c)$.

We must then have $(A+I)\vec{n}=0$. This amount to solving a system of equations:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
  11a+2b+2c=0 \\   
  2a+14b-5c=0\\
  10a-5b-10c=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I find $\vec{n}=(a,b,c)=(-\frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{5},1)$, please double check with a calculator, I did it by hand, prone to errors...

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B11%2F15%2C2%2F15%2C2%2F3%7D%2C%7B2%2F15%2C14%2F15%2C-1%2F3%7D%2C%7B2%2F3%2C-1%2F3%2C-2%2F3%7D%7D) agrees that $\left(-\frac 25,\frac 15,1\right)$ is a solution to $(A+I)n=0$.

Comment: I don't think that's the answer, as the question asks for integers. It also tells us that gcd(|a|,|b|,|c|) = 1.

Comment: @questionasker then go ahead and multiply your normal vector by 5 if this fits your needs: then $\vec{n}=(-2,1,5)$ and this satisfies your gcd condition...

Comment: It says it's incorrect.

Comment: $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{30}}(-2,1,5)$ is correct for $(a,b,c)$, see the [WA result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B11%2F15%2C2%2F15%2C2%2F3%7D%2C%7B2%2F15%2C14%2F15%2C-1%2F3%7D%2C%7B2%2F3%2C-1%2F3%2C-2%2F3%7D%7D%3D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D-2%7B%7Ba%7D%2C%7Bb%7D%2C%7Bc%7D%7D.%7B%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D%7D).